# How to create optional tuple return or unpack

Tags: python, django

I want to send tuple back if function returns error message and the data if success:

Example function:

```
def test(args):
   if (some success here):
     return data
   return None, error_message
```

Call:

```
data, error_msg = test(args)
if error_msg:
   return somehttpresponse(error_msg, 400)
return somehttpresponse(data, 200)
```

How can I achieve this in python? Or is there any other clean way to return error message without compromising the return data on success?

Comment: return this when failure `(None, error_messaage)` and return this when success `(data, None)`

Comment: @RajuKomati "without compromising the return data on success". Not gonna work for me

Comment: @ACDcan you explain what you want to return exactly

Answer (score 0):

So far I used Exception:

Example function:

```
def test(args):
   if (some success here):
     return data
   raise ValueError(error_message)
   return None
```

Call:

```
try:
   data = test(args)
   return somehttpresponse(data, 200)
except ValueError as err:
   return somehttpresponse(err, 400)
```

Not sure if it's the most efficient way. still hoping someone has an answer